# block function to get customer id not works on my accounts custom tab

Tags: magento2, customer-session

My block function to get customer id not works

i'm printing customer details in my accounts custom tab

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;


class myscheme extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{



protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function isCustomerLogged()
{
    if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn())
        return "yes";
    else
        return "no";
}

public function getLoggedCustomerId(){
    return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
class myscheme extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $authContext;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $authContext,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->authContext = $authContext;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function isCustomerLogged()
    {
        $isLoggedIn = $this->authContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn())
            return "yes";
        else
            return "no";
    }

    public function getLoggedCustomerId(){
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    }
}
```

Thanks